# Write an equation for a line

Tags: calculus, geometry

What is the equation for a straight line that passes through the origin and is inclined $\frac{\pi}{3}$ radians from the x-axis? The line passes through the first quadrant.

Is the gradient $\frac{\pi}{3}$?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{3}$ anticlockwise or clockwise from the x-axis?

Comment: clockwise from the x-axis

Comment: How can it pass through the first quadrant if it is inclined clockwise from the x-axis? That would make for a line sloped downwards, that would never pass through the top-right quadrant. Unless you count (0,0) as being in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

- It passes through origin, what can you say about $b$?
- The gradient should involve $\tan$.

Comment: So is this right: $ y = \sqrt{3}x + 0 $ ?

Comment: congratulations, you did it. $y = \sqrt3 x$